# Data recovery on partition encrypted with Veracrypt - Input/Output error - Possible disk failure

Tags: veracrypt, recovery, forensics

I am trying to recover some data from my backup drive which is encrypted with Veracrypt as I recently encountered `input/output error` messages when I attempted to copy some of the files from it. This was after the drive had been successfully mounted and decrypted with Veracrypt:

```bash
$ sudo veracrypt --text --mount /dev/sdb1 /media/veracrypt5 --protect-hidden no --verbose
```

As I suspected possible disk failure to begin with, I decided to image the full drive with `ddrescue` to a separate disk:

```bash
$ sudo ddrescue -c1 -O -a 10M -r3 /dev/sdb disk.img disk-ddrescue.log 

GNU ddrescue 1.23
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
     ipos:    1998 GB, non-trimmed:        0 B,  current rate:   3891 kB/s
     opos:    1998 GB, non-scraped:        0 B,  average rate:  37039 kB/s
non-tried:        0 B,  bad-sector:        0 B,    error rate:       0 B/s
  rescued:    2000 GB,   bad areas:        0,        run time:     15h  6s
pct rescued:  100.00%, read errors:        0,  remaining time:         n/a
 slow reads:     2936,        time since last successful read:         n/a
Finished

$ cat disk-ddrescue.log 
# Mapfile. Created by GNU ddrescue version 1.23
# Command line: ddrescue -c1 -O -a 10M -r3 /dev/sdb disk.img disk-ddrescue.log
# Start time:   2022-06-11 19:58:50
# Current time: 2022-06-12 10:59:08
# Finished
# current_pos  current_status  current_pass
0x1D151B24C00     +               3
#      pos        size  status
0x00000000  0x1D1C1116000  +
```

I checked `dmesg`, and it shows the following errors for the device:

```
[2057020.050884] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-3, logical block 488378288, async page read
[2057020.051069] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-3, logical block 488378288, async page read
[2057020.051105] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-3, logical block 488378302, async page read
[2057021.136808] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-3, logical block 488378288, async page read
[2057021.136863] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-3, logical block 488378288, async page read
[2057024.705572] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-3, logical block 1027, async page read
[2057024.705605] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-3, logical block 1027, async page read
[2057031.930962] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-3, logical block 488378288, async page read
[2057063.008430] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-3, logical block 0, lost sync page write
```

To confirm the errors are actually from the drive in question:

```bash
$ sudo dmsetup info /dev/dm-3
Name:              veracrypt5
State:             ACTIVE
Read Ahead:        256
Tables present:    LIVE
Open count:        1
Event number:      0
Major, minor:      253, 3
Number of targets: 1
```

Output from `sudo fdisk`, `sudo lsblk` and `sudo blkid` after decryption:

```bash
$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sdb: 1,84 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: 002-2DV164      
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 5BB9ECBE-197E-40EE-B85D-D90DF4876C77

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 3907028991 3907026944  1,8T Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/mapper/veracrypt5: 1,84 TiB, 2000397533184 bytes, 3907026432 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

```bash
$ sudo fdisk -lu disk.img
Disk disk.img: 1,84 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 5BB9ECBE-197E-40EE-B85D-D90DF4876C77

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
disk.img1   2048 3907028991 3907026944  1,8T Linux filesystem
```

```bash
$ sudo lsblk
NAME                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
...
sdb                     8:16   0   1,8T  0 disk  
└─sdb1                  8:17   0   1,8T  0 part  
  └─veracrypt5        253:3    0   1,8T  0 dm    /media/veracrypt5
sdc                     8:32   0   4,6T  0 disk  
└─sdc1                  8:33   0   4,6T  0 part  
  └─veracrypt8        253:4    0   4,6T  0 dm    /media/veracrypt8
```

```bash
$ sudo blkid
/dev/mapper/veracrypt8: UUID="26877f0f-d351-478e-9ef5-a0f1c560d53d" TYPE="ext3"
/dev/mapper/veracrypt5: UUID="c0f9c7fe-431c-4a1d-b47a-a583dd3783e3" TYPE="ext3"
/dev/loop7: PTTYPE="atari"
/dev/sdc1: PARTUUID="15ad3a77-6366-4315-b2ef-382988c67b7b"
/dev/sdb1: PTTYPE="atari" PARTUUID="4fc3b79a-c7d1-46bd-ae15-d844b862ed1b"
```

For reference, here is the output of `smartctl -a /dev/sdb`:

```bash
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.13.0-41-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate FireCuda 3.5
Device Model:     ST2000DX002-2DV164
Serial Number:    Z4ZCP6Z5
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0b4ec3ff9
Firmware Version: CC41
User Capacity:    2 000 398 934 016 bytes [2,00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 3b
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 1.5 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Jun 12 20:25:48 2022 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x73) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 230) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x1081) SCT Status supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   101   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       3415264
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   098   095   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       826
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   081   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       150879843
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   073   073   000    Old_age   Always       -       23876
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   020    Old_age   Always       -       2029
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       2
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       6
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   064   049   045    Old_age   Always       -       36 (Min/Max 32/36)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       25
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       5451
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   036   051   000    Old_age   Always       -       36 (0 11 0 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       11
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       21475h+37m+00.325s
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       30779265742
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       288499467100

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

An interesting part is that when I mount the image to a loopback device and fsck it, I get the following:

```bash
$ losetup -f
/dev/loop7

# mount disk image to loopback device, -o 1048576 because of offset of 2048 and sector size of 512 = 2048*512
$ sudo losetup -o 1048576 /dev/loop7 disk.img

# running fsck on loopback device
$ sudo fsck -fv /dev/loop7
fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/loop7

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Found a atari partition table in /dev/loop7
```

If I try to mount `disk.img` directly to another mount point which is not a loopback and using the same offset, I get another error:

```bash
$ sudo mount -o loop,offset=1048576 disk.img /mnt/sshd1
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/loop7': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/loop7' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

```bash
$ file disk.img 
disk.img: DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0xee, start-CHS (0x0,0,2), end-CHS (0x3ff,255,63), startsector 1, 3907029167 sectors, extended partition table (last)
```

I am not sure why `mount` and `file` auto detects this as `NTFS`/`msdos`. Could it be that Windows has overwritten the super-block or part of the partition table when the disk was connected to the Windows workstation?

My goal is simple: I just want to recover the data in the Veracrypt volume but I am not sure how to go forth, since when I attempt to copy the data after decryption, I only get `input/output error` messages, or the drive just disconnects and gives off a clicking noise (not good). It is possible to navigate the drive after decryption to see the file names. I can also see that some file sizes are not correct, indicating corruption. My thoughts are that it may be possible to recover some of the files with `testdisk` if I can just the image mounted correctly.

I also find it quite weird that the disk only acts weird when I attempt to access files after decryption, but when cloning the drive no errors occur?

Link to a similar problem: ["NTFS signature is missing." How to mount this HDD? (or is it password protected?)](https://superuser.com/questions/1185158/ntfs-signature-is-missing-how-to-mount-this-hdd-or-is-it-password-protected)

Comment: It looks to me you have the right idea, but you are not unlocking the Veracrypt drive on the loopback image. My understanding (and its been a long time since I used its predecessor Truecrypt) is that Veracrypt behaves as a block device, so you would need to mount the loopback, then use veracrypt to decrypt that - creating another block device you can then mount.

Comment: @davidgo Thank you, that worked! I managed to mount it using: `sudo veracrypt --text --mount /dev/loop7 /media/veracrypt6 --protect-hidden no --verbose`. I assume I can continue my forensics with `testdisk` now that I have it mounted as well. I will give it a try.

Comment: On second thoughts, would that even be possible? `/dev/loop7` would still be the unencrypted data unless I am mistaken, and I can not run `testdisk` right on the mount point `/media/veracrypt6`.

Comment: I don't know much about testdisk in this scenario as I've only used it for partition recovery which is not applicable.  If you are using testidsk you can't use it on /media/veracrypt.  Assuming /dev/loop7 is the loopback device of your encrypted image you cant use it there either.  Can you advise the details of "df" and "lsblk" as these might give us some clues.  I imagine that Veracrypt will create a new block device you can use for recovery.  If not, "Cryptsetup" claims limited support for Veracrypt  - and if you can open the disk with that it will expose a block device.

Comment: When you update your post, it often makes sense to also add a comment referencing a user who you are responding to - eg @davidgo so they get a notification.  I stumbled across your updated info almost by accident.

Comment: It looks like lsblk is telling you what the veracrypt block devices are - eg /dev/mapper/veracrypt5 - although this looks to be the original disk based instance, not the instance mounted off the image.   Was the image instance mounted when you did that command?

Comment: @davidgo - Sorry, I only tagged on the first reply. To clarify, in the output `/dev/mapper/veracrypt5` is the actual faulty disk connected and decrypted. I included the output just for information. The instance mounted off the image is on `/dev/loop7`. After I decrypted `/dev/loop7` with veracrypt, I managed to copy out some of the files that were not corrupted. The next step I have to perform is to recover the data using `testdisk` or similar software. I tried to follow the documentation here https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk:_undelete_file_for_FAT, but it seems like the FS is broken.

Comment: @davidgo - I also found in the [Veracrypt troubleshooting guide](https://veracrypt.eu/en/docs/troubleshooting/) some information regarding an error I got from when I attempted to decrypt on my Windows machine: `This device does not contain a valid file system`. I decided to test this on the faulty disk, and when running a `Repair filesystem` in Veracrypt the error message `CHKDSK is not available for RAW drives.` is returned. I assume RAW ==  None FS in `testdisk`, but `testdisk` does not seem to support undeleting files without FS type. Output of `df` & `lsblk`: https://pastebin.com/we09VeUn

Comment: The reason you are getting "This device does not contain a valid filesystem" may be because you were trying to work on the encrypted version of the block device.

Answer (score 0):

Per your pastebin the device to operate on is /dev/mapper/veracrypt6 (You can see under sudo lsblk that veracrypt6 is a child of loop7).

You will want to unmount the filesystem first to prevent further corruption, ie with

```
 umount /media/veracrypt6
```

Once you have done this, you should be able to attempt whatever block/filesystem recovery operations you need to on /dev/mapper/veracrypt6

Attempting to undelete files requires the program doing the undelete is aware of the filesystem and makes use of filesystem specific references to facilitate the undelete if possible.      The alternative to this is to use something like photorec (part of the testdisk suite) to look at the raw disk and pull off whatever it can recognise - this gives you more files, but has disadvantage of not handling files which are fragmented, not knowing file names and only being able to recover some file types (it attempts its recovery based on signatures it recognizes in a raw stream of data.   This means it can't use filenames as they are stored in a different part of the filesystem, and it does not, for the most part, know how to link up files spread over different parts of the filesystem, or what files were meant to be deleted etc).